# How to implement two while loops back to back in MIPS

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am working on a project assignment using MARS MIPS simulator.

As part of the requirement, I have to compute the n!/(n - r)! of the combination formula using a loop and the 1/r! portion using the recursive factorial function. The factorial portion appears to work fine but I am struggling with the loop portion.

For a total of 4 inputs (2 r's and 2 n's), I am using two while loops; the first while loop is able to get the desired result which is 254251200, however I keep getting 1 as the result from the second while loop. If I place the second while loop before the first while loop, I end up with 1 from the first while loop and 110 from the second while loop. It seems like each loop standalone is working but putting adjacent to each other doesn't work. I am still very new to MIPS code and how I can get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
.data
    new_line: .asciiz "\n"
        
.text
    addi $t0, $zero, 50
    addi $t1, $zero, 5
    sub $t2, $t0, $t1
    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    
    addi $t3, $zero, 11
    addi $t4, $zero, 2
    sub $t5, $t3, $t4
    addi $s1, $s1, 1

while1:
    ble $t0, $t2, exit
    mul $s0, $t0, $s0
    addi $t0, $t0, -1
    j while1
    
while2:
    ble $t3, $t5, exit
    mul $s1, $t3, $s1
    addi $t3, $t3, -1
    j while2
    
exit:
    move $a0, $s0,
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    la $a0, new_line
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    
    move $a0, $s1
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: How are you ever going to reach `while2` in the code you've shown us?

Comment: Also, what is `addi $s0, $s0, 1` supposed to do? Did you mean `addi $s0, $zero, 1` (or simply `li $s0, 1`)?

Comment: I was under the impression that it wouId enter the second while loop after the first. I realized it is not working that way. Could you please shed some lights on how to get this to work? Yes, it was a typo I was intending to say addi $s0, $zero, 1.

Comment: Well, instead of jumping to `exit` from the first loop, shouldn't you be jumping to `while2`, since that's where you want to go next?

Comment: I switched the label "exit" to "while2" in the first while loop. It is working like a cham. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in while1 you're jumping to exit. This way the code will never run while2. Instead of jumping to exit jump to while2. Try the following code:

```
 .data
    new_line: .asciiz "\n"
        
   .text
    addi $t0, $zero, 50
    addi $t1, $zero, 5
    sub $t2, $t0, $t1
    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    
    addi $t3, $zero, 11
    addi $t4, $zero, 2
    sub $t5, $t3, $t4
    addi $s1, $s1, 1

while1:
    ble $t0, $t2, while2
    mul $s0, $t0, $s0
    addi $t0, $t0, -1
    j while1
    
while2:
    ble $t3, $t5, exit
    mul $s1, $t3, $s1
    addi $t3, $t3, -1
    j while2
    
exit:
    move $a0, $s0,
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    la $a0, new_line
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    
    move $a0, $s1
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```